# A word for someone who goes too easy on him or herself

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

They don’t push themselves hard enough, and sometimes they do not have the same expectation for themselves as they do for others.

They make excuses for themselves, saying stuff like: “ I’m still a work in progress”

Comment: I'm fairly sure 'self-indulgent' has this as a sub-sense (though it's not the default sense). See [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/indulgent): indulgent 
ADJECTIVE
1 Having or indicating a readiness or over-readiness to be generous to **or lenient with** someone....

‘self-indulgent'.